# How to convert PDF to HTML in react-native

Tags: react-native

I am looking for way/library to convert `PDF` to `HTML` in `react-native`.

I want to be able to manipulate the html later on.

Is this possible in react-native

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for the convert pdf to html format

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf2html

Comment: `Java runtime environment (JRE) is required to run this module` it is for node I think. Not for react-native